# GetElementByTagName in specific class?

Tags: javascript

How would I go about getting an element by TagName if it falls under a specific class?

Example, if I wanted to select each `<li>` TagName which is within the test_class.

```
<ul class="test_class">
    <li>
        1
    </li>
    <li>
        2
    </li>
    <li>
        3
    </li>
    <li>
        4
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.test_class li')` :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

- Get a reference to the element that is a member of that class, and then call `getElementsByTagName` on that DOM element *or*
- Use [`document.querySelectorAll(".test_class li")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) which accepts a CSS Selector

Use the first approach if you need to support old-IE.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".test_class li");
//=> [li, li, li, li]
```

Supported by

```
Browser    Version
Chrome     1
Firefox    3.5
IE         8 (CSS2 selectors only)
IE         9
Opera      10
Safari     3.2
```

---

If you need to support older browsers, you can't depend on `.querySelectorAll`

```
// find all UL.test_class
var lists = document.getElementsByClassName("test_class"),
    listItems = [];

// loop through all lists and concat all children LI elements to single result
for (var i=0, len=lists.length; i<len; i++) {
  listItems.concat(lists[i].getElementsByTagName("li"));
}

console.log(listItems);
//=> [li, li, li, li]
```

---

Performance

To no surprise, the `.querySelectorAll` is only marginally slower, but wow it sure is concise. I wouldn't prematurely optimize in this scenario unless you truly needed to support older browsers (IE <= 7)

http://jsperf.com/qsa-vs-getelementbytagname

Answer (score 1):

You could chain the DOM query.

```
var items = document
              .getElementsByClassName('test_class')[0]
              .getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Comment: Ironically that it doesn't make sense to go with `getElementsByClassName (IE9+)` + `getElementsByTagName` if you can use `querySelectorAll (IE8+)`, since later will have better IE support. But for the sake of completeness it should also be upvoted.